# Woocommerce - Reserved status

Tags: woocommerce

I'm trying to create my shop (art pictures), all products are unique.
All sales are "cash on delivery" and I wonder if it's possible to display 3 differents states for a product :
 - product available 
 - product sold-out
 - product reserved

This last state means that the user have finish to complete his card and just wait for my approval. Is it possible to do ?

Comment: In stock and out of stock are built-in depending on stock status. I'm not sure  how you'd go about setting up a "reserved" status. You could definitely set up a meta key for when the item is reserved and check against that.

Comment: By the way, the `is_in_stock()` method definitely cannot be filtered, so you would need to write an entirely new function.